# Do Mappers and Reducers in Hadoop have to be static classes?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm attempting to do something simple in Hadoop and found that when writing mappers and reducers are defined as static everywhere. My task is going to be decomposed into several `map` parts and one final `reduce`. What if I'd like to reuse one of my mappers in other job? If I have my mapper class defined as inner `static` one can I use it in other job? Also non-trivial problems may require many more and complicated mappers, so putting them all in one giant file gets terrible when maintaining.

Is there any way to have mappers and reducers as a regular classes (possibly even in separate jar) than the job itself?

Answer (score 9):

Is your question whether the class has to be static, may be static, or may be inner, or should be inner?

Hadoop itself needs to be able to instantiate your `Mapper` or `Reducer` by reflection, given the class reference/name configured in your `Job`. This will fail if it is a non-static inner class since an instance can be created only in the context of some other of your classes which presumably Hadoop knows nothing about. (Unless the inner class extends its enclosing class, I suppose.)

So to answer the first question: it should not be non-static, since this almost surely makes it unusable. To answer the second and third: and it can be a static (inner) class.

To me a `Mapper` or `Reducer` is plainly a top-level concept and deserves a top-level class. Some like to make them inner static to pair them with a "Runner" class. I don't like this as it is really what subpackages are for. You note another design reason to avoid this. To the fourth question: no, I believe inner classes are not good practice.

Final question: yes the `Mapper` and `Reducer` classes can be in a separate JAR file. You tell Hadoop which JAR files contains all of this code, and that's the one it will ship off to workers. The workers don't need your `Job`. However they need anything that the `Mapper` and `Reducer` depends on in their same JAR.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the above answer is much precise and does satisfy the rationale. Except, I feel that inner classes should be harnessed while creating the map and reduce. IMO, all the code should be at one place.

And generics can be utilised thoughtfully in the single class ensuring there are no typecasting errors.

Comment: It's not an answer. You can leave a comment if you get sufficient reputations.