# Can Mapper and Reducer be on separate jars

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In a MapReduce job I understand it is possible for the Job runner class itself to reside in a separate jar than the mapper and reducer ([check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828131/do-mappers-and-reducers-in-hadoop-have-to-be-static-classes))
And that the setJarByClass is the place in the job I'd pass that separate jar info.
Is there a way, however, to have the mapper and reducer each in its own separate jar?

10x!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have Mapper and Reducer in separate JARs.

What I have done in the past to enable this is:

1. Place the required JARS that contain Mapper and Reducer on the HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable
2. Provide the JARS that contain Mapper and Reducer to the Hadoop Distributed Cache via -libjars option using Hadoop ToolRunner, if the Mapper/Reducer are not included in the Driver JAR.
3. Manually load the Mapper and Reducer classes onto the runtime classpath with the appropriate Java ClassLoader

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be done with distributed cache ? Sound pretty weird, can't I just export the package which has 3 classes (mapper,driver,reducer) into 1 jar file?